# How to fix "no executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"" with the new csproj file

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'd like to use SQLite with Entity Framework Core. I'm following this official tutorial:

[.NET Core - New Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite)

It says to modify the project.json like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4"
  }
}
```

I have installed the VS 2017 RC and Net Core now uses the csproj file instead of project.json.

I modified my csproj to `Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version= "1.1.0-preview4-final"` but when I try the command `dotnet ef migrations add MyFirstMigration` I get the following error:

**"no executable found matching command "dotnet-ef""**

How can I fix this with the new csproj?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS2017 will be officially released on the 7th of March 2017. The doc concerns VS2015, they have not been updated yet to reflect the latest VS 2017 changes. Modifying the csproject like this solves the problem:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version = "1.1.0-preview4-final"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Even after this, when I tried to run the first migration with the CLI command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add MyFirstMigration
```

I got the following error: 
***“No parameterless constructor was found on 'TContext'. Either add a parameterless constructor to 'TContext' or add an implementation of 'IDbContextFactory' in the same assembly as 'TContext'.”***

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet) document, this happens because design-time tools attempt to automatically find how your application creates instances of your DbContext type. If EF cannot find a suitable way to initialize your DbContext, you may encounter this error.

I was pretty sure I had setup a parameterless constructor and I was able to see the context with the following CLI command:

```
dotnet ef database dbContext list
```

The only way to perform the migration has been to implement the interface `IDbContextFactory<TContext>` in the project. The documentation and the examples on how to do this are based on VS 2015. In VS 2017 `IDbContextFactory<TContext>.Create()` wants a `DBContextFactoryOptions` as parameter:

```
public class MyContextFactory: IDbContextFactory<MyContext>   
{
    public MyContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();       
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=./mydatabase.db");

        return new MyContext(optionsBuilder.Options);        
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also advise to use 1.1.0 version for Microsoft.Extensions.* (or any other ASP.NET package) for aligning them.

Comment: Maybe you are too hard when you say that the documentation on the Microsoft website is outdated. The doc concerns VS2015 so this is why there is a (fully accurate) example of project.json. VS2017 will be officially released on the 7th of March 2017.
However my questions is: what are declaring `1.0.0-msbuild3-final` for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` tool? Does it mean there is no 1.1.0 tooling if you are using msbuild? (I am still on VS2015)